# Passing a struct instance to function not throwing error

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I have this situation:

```
struct A {};

void foo(A& a) {};
void boo(const A& a) {};

void foo(int& a) {};
void boo(const int& a) {};

int main() {
    foo(A()); //ok... but why?
    boo(A()); //ok

    foo(5); //error
    boo(5); //ok

    return 0;
}
```

Why `foo(A())` works while `foo(5)` does not? Wouldn't it be the same situation? Is `A()` on `foo(A())` an `rvalue`? Can I consider `A()` in this situation a temporary object?

Comment: `foo(A());` Should not work. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (v140).

Comment: Visual Studio accepts this code, but not gcc. You should consider adding `const` for better portability.

Comment: remove *permissive* extension.

Comment: the /permissive- is just for VS 2017+? Right?

Comment: MSVC has for a long time incorrectly allowed that, and hasn't fixed it entirely in order to avoid breaking older code, but there are now settings to switch it to the correct behavior.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo It looks like yes, `/permissive-` is only known by 2017 and later. But https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-referencebinding-enforce-reference-binding-rules?view=vs-2015 doesn't mention any versions, so maybe manually adding `/Zc:referenceBinding` to the compile command line would work.